# [BFTask isFaulted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0, bftask

Updated to Parse SDK 1.7.1 with Bolts 1.1.4 and using the new and latest Facebook SDK. Every time I login the user I get the following error:

[BFTask isFaulted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

I'm able to login the user, the user's info is store in parse, but not sure how to resolve this exception.

Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: I am currently facing the problem as well, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Yes i was - i hope by now the facebook sdk and parse sdk documentation is upadted. I am not near my computer right now, but from what i remember is that you have to make sure that you have the latest bolt framework in your project. The lastest from parse not the one that comes with facebook. Also make sure both parse and facebook frameworks are the latest. Other than that I'd have to look at my code later tonight as some of the blocks are a bit different than what facebook and parse provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this problem also.
I copied the Parse Bolts framework to the project directory. Referencing didn't do it. Same for Parse FacebookutilsV4.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem just a minute ago.
You need update the latest FacebookSDK to avoid this error.
You can just download the latest SDK from facebook website.

However if you just drag the parse and facebook framework together into the project, maybe a 'duplicate' error will be reported.

**So I recommend you to use CocoaPods to manage your thirdparty framework.**