# Parse loginWithUsernameInBackground block callback not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, parse-platform

I have a parse app in the appstore already. I'm about to submit an update for the app using the latest Parse SDK 1.7.4 and I noticed the manual parse login IS NOT WORKING!

I hope this is due to my code and not a parse issue.

Here is the code:

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {        
if (!error) {
   //do stuff with user
} else { 
   //error handling here     
}
```

I of course did some search on the internet to find an answer and most people are saying not to use the background functions because things need to run on the main thread. And I tried using the dispatch async and forced it to run on the main thread but still no callback from the login.

Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
-[BFTask isFaulted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance  
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BFTask isFaulted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

When I run the below code:

```
NSError *error;
PFUser *user = (PFUser *)[PFUser logInWithUsername:username password:password error:&error];
if (error) {
   //do error handling here
} else {
   //do stuff with user object here and go to logged in screen.
}
```

Also, I want to note, I have this:

```
NSString *const BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";
```

in my AppDelegate just to be able to compile and run the app ever since I upgraded to Parse 1.7.4 SDK.

These are the errors I get if I take out this line from the AppDelegate:

```
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke226 in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke319 in Parse(PFObject.o)
```

[Here is a question](https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-sdk-loginwithusernameinbackgroundpasswordblock-does-not-execute-block-on-error-case) that's similar to this in Parse blogs that's not really solved:

https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-sdk-loginwithusernameinbackgroundpasswordblock-does-not-execute-block-on-error-case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30523757/1702413

Comment: try to update to the last Bolts vers 1.2.0 https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS/releases/tag/1.2.0

Comment: Thanks for the link @TonyMkenu but copying the bolts framework to project and then linking it didn't work. It's giving me this error: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._URL in:
 /Users/kaanersan/Projects/../Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
 /Users/kaanersan/Projects/../FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o)

Comment: I'm gonna try updating to Bolts 1.2.0 now

Comment: Nope, still same error with Bolts 1.2.0 unfortunately. The duplicate symbol error. I'm gonna try taking it out and running.

Comment: Yeah, when I take out the Bolts framework, I'm back to this error: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke226 in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke319 in Parse(PFObject.o) without the const string in the AppDelegate code as I was mentioning in the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840546/facebooksdk-and-bolts-conflicting-each-other-duplicate-symbols-on-build

Comment: These still don't work properly. I created a parse project from scratch and that works of course but still don't know how to fix my existing project which is a pain.

Comment: Have you tried removing all Parse-related libraries from the project, downloading the most recent libraries and configuring it again?

Comment: I did, but not completely. I'm going to try that again. BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException line as I mentioned in the question frustrates me. I don't want that in the project at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot comment on your question (not enough reputation), but it seems you have an old FacebookSDK in your project. Xcode gives you a duplicate symbols error, which is caused by the fact that your (old) FacebookSDK has Bolts integrated. The moment you integrate it from the Parse SDK, you have it effectively two times in your project, resulting in the duplicate symbols error.

Please update your FacebookSDK to the last v3 version, available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x). Then, use the latest ParseSDK, and include everything from Parse (also ParseUI, Bolts, etc, everything from their SDK folder EXCEPT the v4Facebook framework) into your project.

This should do the trick and your method:

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {        
if (!error) {
   //do stuff with user
} else { 
   //error handling here     
}
```

should work.

Comment: Ohhhhh buddy that was it. I tried removing and re-adding the libraries but I think the issue is that Parse isn't compatible with Facebook's newest SDK (v4) so last v3.23.2 worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I gave you your points :) Also one thing to mention is that I had to include libstdc++.6.dylib in the project to get rid of the errors I got after re-adding all of Parse and FB libraries.

Comment: Great to hear you solved your problem. You should check against the list on the Parse QuickStart Guide, they have listed all the required libraries there.